# How to configure cordova installed plugins in Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I have completed the following steps:

1. I currently have a cordova created project using the Cordova CLI.
2. I have installed plugins using `plugin add *`
3. My project runs successfully as do the plugins when I `cordova emulate android`

Now I wish to go down the SDK route (no longer the CLI) to make specific changes to the Android platform files. I have:

1. Created a new Android Studio project
2. Imported the output from `platforms/android` directory
3. Added dependency to `CordovaLib` in `platforms/android` directory

I can now build successfully and run the app on an emulator but none of my previously installed plugins from the CLI are running. Instead the following errors are logged:

```
"deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1154)
"Channel not fired: onPluginsReady", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1147)
"Channel not fired: onCordovaReady", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1147)
"Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1147)
```

Can anyone explain how to configure cordova installed plugins from the CLI and use them in the SDK route in Android Studio?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are accessible only after the deviceReady event. Have you defined the device ready in the index.html ? can you please provide the code you used?

Comment: These errors are not related to the deviceReady event not being called correctly. I know this as when I run Cordova on the CLI i.e. `cordova emulate android` everytihg works as expected. The problem is related to the configuration of the android platform (`platforms\android`) within Android Studio with plugins included.

Answer (score 0):

no need of creating the android studio project.
directly open the android studio and import platforms/android project.
in the project you will get the plugin files in src folder with respective plugin package names.
their you can make specific changes.